# php error on my error_log while posting

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

this is my php codes getting Post Successfully response when true but when it failed for some reason.
i got this error.

> mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) ;
    if($result){$response["msg"] = "Post Successfully";
echo json_encode($response);} else {$response["msg"] = "failed ".mysqli_error($con);
echo json_encode($response);
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

Comment: `mysqli_error($con)` should be `mysqli_error($connection)`

Comment: $con is null...

Answer (score 1):

`$con` is null

`mysqli_error($con);` should be  `mysqli_error($connection);`  as you have declared connection as `$connection`.

Answer (score 1):

According to this line:

```
mysqli_query($connection, $query)
```

You are using variable `$connection` for link identifier, and in `mysqli_error($con)` you are using `$con` variable which is undefined or NULL, this should be:

```
mysqli_error($connection)
```